# Map JSON data and put it into an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift3

I have the following problem.

I use Alamofire request. The response is a JSON.

```
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON {
        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {

            print("Success! Got the korosztaly data")
            let koJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)


           print(koJSON)

        }
        else {
            print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
        }
    }
```

The result of the koJSON is the following:

```
{ "members": [ {"name": "Sarah"}, {"name": "David"}, {"name": "Michael"} ] }
```

I want to create an Members array and put all of the data into it.
The result should be the following

`Members = ["Sarah", "David", "Michael"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use the map function. It will iterate over each item in the array and allow you to pull out the selected information, or do a transformation on it.

```
if let resp = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject], 
      let membersArr = resp["members"] as? [[String: String]] {
   let members = membersArr.map { $0["name"] }
}
```

Output should be as expected.

You can read more about map and other high order functions [here](https://medium.com/@Dougly/higher-order-functions-in-swift-sorted-map-filter-reduce-dff60b5b6adf)

Comment: "Cast from 'JSON' to unrelated type '[[String : String]]' always fails" - is the message..

Comment: "Type 'Any' has no subscript members" is the error message

Comment: I have updated the answer, try that. I think Alamofire automatically casts as String: Any

Comment: Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : AnyObject]]' with an index of type 'String' error at your second line.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i updated again. first cast should be `[String: AnyObject]` not `[[String: AnyObject]]`

Comment: Super! It works now! But the printed result has an "Optional" tag: [Optional("Sarah"), Optional("David"), Optional("Michael")]

Comment: that just means that the strings are optional. you can force cast them as you know they are Strings. `let members = membersArr.map { $0["name"]! }`